# How to identify a use case for a lifecycle hook vs function in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

I have been self-learning Angular bit by bit and have come to the topic of lifecycle hooks.

Lifecycle hooks are basically self-triggering events that happen naturally when a component is created and destroyed and implement a specific interface from `@angular/core`

My question is when should I be able to say "This needs a hook"? 
Ideally:

- If you have code to repeat you use a function
- If you have a decision to make you use if/else

Is there such a distinction for using hook?
From the official docs:

> Angular offers lifecycle hooks that provide visibility into these key life moments and the ability to act when they occur. A directive has the same set of lifecycle hooks.

What I don't understand is how this would be practical or why you would need to do this.

Comment: when you want something to be done as soon as the component done loading, you can only use `ngOnInit()`. if you have a valid subscription in your component, you must unsubscribe it, and the best place to do it, is on `ngOnDestroy()`. I can give you hundreds of practical examples I really can't understand your question.

Comment: And when you want to execute some code as soon as the view has been rendered, you can put the code in `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: So based off the last two comments this is what I've surmised. Each hook fits different use cases of which there can be hundreds of examples. But the core goal of them is having different things happen to the component or template at specific points in it's lifecycle. So when there is async data (observable or promise) or an event chain for example rather than writing custom events it'd be better to find a hook that fits the scenario. So in summation, you should try a hook before writing a custom event. Does that  sound correct?

Comment: Putting code in a life cycle hook is like handling a DOM event. The decision is not so much about `what` you want to do but rather `when` you want to do it. If you want some code to be executed when an event occurs in the "life" of a component, you put the code in the corresponding life cycle hook.

Comment: To me it looks like your question should rather be "What are lifecycle events". There seems to be some confusion about them.

Comment: @Callat - For async operations (observable, promise), you should put the code in the callback (subscribe, then), instead of trying to put it in a life cycle hook.

Comment: Ok thank you, I have a better understanding based from your responses. The concept seemed really odd add first but basically they are Angular specific event handlers that aim to streamline a workflow. If you'd like to post your comments as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @abetteroliver I didn't ask that because it's not a `what is X?` it's more of a `why would I use X?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put code in a lifecycle hook if you want it to be executed when an event occurs in the life of an Angular component or at various stages of the change detection cycle. The principle is somewhat similar to handling DOM events. The decision is based on **when** you want to execute the code, rather than **what** kind of code will be executed.

The complete list of lifecycle hooks is given in [the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence). Here are a few examples:

- ngOnInit() - When the component is initialized
- ngAfterViewInit() - When the component view is initialized
- ngOnDestroy() - When the component is about to be destroyed
- ngOnChanges() - When data bound input properties are changed
- etc.

In other cases, like DOM events, Observables, or Promises, you should execute the code in the callback to these events instead of trying to run it in a lifecycle hook.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @ConnorsFan